# How to get realtime data from hardware sensors and see the results in Kaa platform?

Tags: java, mongodb, sensors, iot, kaa

I have made a single node of Kaa platform. on the other side, I have some sensors, like temperature, humidity and so on.

Now I want to connect these sensors to the single node of Kaa and receive data from them and see the recorded data in my application. How can I do it? 
I know I should use a log appender and I also installed MongoDB Compass. but I don't know how to get real data from them in Java application, and save them into the database and then see the results in whether Java Application or  MongoDB Compass.

I am a little  confused with the usage of this platform.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

**From my side experience, you need this formula:**

**1.** Start small thing and get the experience

**2.** After that, you are able to better understanding

**3.** Finally, you can start your idea

**Note**: This is not a complete solution but you need get your experience and do more thing for getting your desired goal.

---

**According to above point:**

**1.** You should know that how sensor working: (Like this "[Datasheet](https://akizukidenshi.com/download/ds/aosong/DHT11.pdf)" for DHT11 sensor)

**2.** Write your require implementation of some custom logic (driver) for the desired sensor according to the instructions datasheet.

**3.** Data modeling according to require data for sensor (Log record schema)

**4.** To get real-time analytics data you can use Cassandra DB that it is a very good idea for the temperature sensor.(Kaa currently supports for NoSQL data storage: Cassandra)

**5.** After that, you need to generate the desired SDK according to language programming that Kaa is supported.

---

Check out the below links for more details:

[Real-time IoT data analytics and visualization with Kaa, Apache Cassandra, and Apache Zeppelin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MFdQvlnptsM)

[Time series IoT data ingestion into Cassandra using Kaa](https://www.kaaproject.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/IoT-data-ingestion-into-Cassandra.pdf)

Hope to be useful to you.